# template custom data for stormpath account

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

Can I have a JSON template that is automatically assigned to the custom data field of every newly created user in Stormpath?

At the moment I am attempting to copy my JSON template to account.customData in the postRegistrationHandler function but I'm struggling to copy it properly.

So I've got...

```
 postRegistrationHandler: function (account, req, res, next) {
    console.log('User:', account.email, 'just registered!');
    writeCustomDataToAccount(account, customDataBlank);
    next();
},
```

with 'customDataBlank' being a .json file on server. And then...

```
var writeCustomDataToAccount = function (account, customData) {
account.getCustomData(function (err, data) {
    for (var field in customData) {
        data[field] = customData[field];
    }
    data.save();
});
```

}

does that look sensible?

**EDIT:**
well I'm now able to copy my JSON better than I was doing but my question still stands - *Can I have a JSON template that is automatically assigned to the custom data field of every newly created user in Stormpath?*

Comment: Hi Nic, this looks correct - is the problem that you're not seeing the data being saved the the account's custom data object?  P.S. I work at Stormpath :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me -- I'm the author of the express-stormpath library. What your code will do in that `postRegistrationHandler` is automatically store some Custom Data for every newly created user.

I did notice one thing that's off, however -- if your file is on disk, it doesn't look like you're loading it anywhere. What I'd do is this:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  postRegistrationHandler: function(account, req, res, next) {
    console.log('User:', account.email, 'just registered!');
    account.getCustomData(function(err, data) {
      if (err) return next(err);

      var dataToStore = require(customDataBlank); // this will load JSON from the file on disk
      for (var field in require(customDataBlank)) {
        data[field] = dataToStore[field];
      }
      data.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        next();
      });
    });
  },
}));
```

Comment: Hey Randall, was hoping you'd answer this one :) as you seem to do all the other Stormpath queries on here .

I had been loading the json file into a variable then using that but your way might be nicer and prevent creating this variable outside of the function :-/. I have this working now as I want so I guess my question now (and it's not super important) is 'Can I specify a JSON template that Stormpath applies to every user created for my application?' I mean, that wouldn't be so different to my writing the template in the postReg function so no biggie. cheers man!

Comment: Hey Nic, you can't do that right now -- this is actually a great suggestion though! I'll pass this along to our engineering team and see what they think =)